# Auto-Generate PDF with Image (actual image, not link) and Data Input in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I'm creating a google form one can fill out to auto-generate a Digital Millennium Copyright Act notice as a PDF. The notice requires the original image in question to be included, so the form includes an upload file question. I want the generated PDF to include the actual image that was uploaded in the form, but right now all I get is the google drive link to the file's location.

How can I get the actual image to appear in the PDF? I'm attaching a screenshot of the Google Form, email output, and PDF template (marked with where the image should go) for reference.

[image: google form]
[image: email]
[image: template]

Here's the script I have on the Google Sheet that's populated by the Google Form submissions:

````
function onSubmit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;
  console.log(rg.getA1Notation());
  const sh = rg.getSheet();
  
  //Get all the form submitted data
  //Note: This data is dependent on the headers. If headers, are changed update these as well.
  const Email= e.namedValues['Email Address'][0];
  const LinkOrig = e.namedValues['Link(s) for where the original work appears'][0];
  const AttachOrig = e.namedValues['Copies of the original copyrighted work'][0];
  const Domain = e.namedValues['Infringing Domain'][0];
  const LinkInfring = e.namedValues['Link(s) for where infringing image appears online'][0];
  const Contact = e.namedValues['Contact Information'][0];
  const WHOIS = e.namedValues['WHOIS Search results'][0];
  const Date = e.namedValues['Date'][0];
  const Location = e.namedValues['Where are you based?'][0];
  
  //Build a new DMCA Form from the template
  //Folder ID (save destination) and file IDs (template ID + new doc ID)
  const DMCAFolderID = 'folderidhere';
  const DMCALibFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DMCAFolderID);
  
  const TemplateFileID = 'templateidhere';
  const newFilename = 'DMCA Notice -' + TemplateFileID + 'Domain';
  
  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newTemplateFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, DMCALibFolder).getId();;
  
  //Get the DMCA Notice body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplateFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();
  
  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the template body
  body.replaceText('{{LinkOrig}}', LinkOrig);
  body.replaceText('{{AttachOrig}}', AttachOrig);
  body.replaceText('{{LinkInfring}}', LinkInfring);
  body.replaceText('{{ContactInfo}}', Contact);
  body.replaceText('{{WHOISResults}}', WHOIS);
  body.replaceText('{{date}}', Date);
  body.replaceText('{{location}}', Location);
  
  document.saveAndClose();

// define email variables
var subject = 'DMCA Notice - ' + Domain;
var msgHtml = 
"Hi," + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Please find your DMCA Notice attached." + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Sincerely," + "<br/>" +
"Your Bada** Self" + "<br/>" 
;
var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(newTemplateFileID);

//send email with the file
GmailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, msgHtml, {htmlBody: msgHtml, attachments: [attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  }```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? In your script, I think that the event object of `e` is the sample input value. And also, can you provide the sample output situation as an image?

Comment: No need to apologize! I added a screenshot of the Google Form, the template, and the email output into the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assuming that `{{AttachOrig}}` is your placeholder and `AttachOrig` the URL of the file

You need to:

- Obtain the image blob from the URL by opening it with DriveApp and getting the blob
- Find the placeholder in your template
- Replace the text by an empty string
- Find the element that contains the placeholder
- Get the element's parent paragraph
- Insert the image blob into the parent paragraph

**Sample:**

```
var AttachOrig = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8EFG6G5zNd6by_fNEecSh2D1My_p-_p/view";

function replacePlaceHolderThroughImage() {
   ...
    var document = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplateFileID);
    var body = document.getBody();
    var placeholder = "{{AttachOrig}}";
    var id = AttachOrig.match(/[\w\_\-]{25,}/)[0];
    var img = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var position = body.findText(placeholder);
    var element = position.getElement();
    element.asText().setText("");
    element.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, img.getBlob());
}
```

Comment: @zignotschka That cat photo tho!

Super basic question probably... how do I define the AttachOrig var that way if the google drive file is being generated as part of the upload (eg it isn't pre-existing, it's added to drive when the form is submitted, so I don't have a drive link to plug into the script)

Comment: As far as I understood- as your code is now, it already generates the link for the dynamically uploaded file (and this link replaced the placeholder). Did I understand correctly that this link is contained in the car `AttachOrig`?

Comment: I hope I'm answering your question here and not misunderstanding! 
Yes, the form submission creates the Google Drive link for the dynamically uploaded file (which is then contained in the var `AttachOrig`)

Comment: Then all you need to do is to integrate my code sample in your already existing code -skipping the line that manually sets `attachOrig` to the cat picture URL.

Comment: That did the trick! I'm sufficiently new at this that it took me a bit to realize that `function replacePlaceHolderThroughImage(e)` was meant to replace `function onSubmit(e)` once I got that and added the new lines, it worked like magic! Thank you!!